# How to generate file with all string that match pattern from another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have file like this:

```
Dir1/File1.cpp Dir2/File2.cpp \
Dir3/File1.h Dir4/File2.cpp \
Dir2/File1.cpp \
Dir2/File1.h \
```

I want to generate file like this:

```
Dir1/File1.cpp
Dir2/File2.cpp
Dir3/File1.h
Dir4/File2.cpp
Dir2/File1.cpp
Dir2/File1.h
```

How to do this by using Bash/Sed/Awk/Grep or something like this?

Comment: `Dir1/File1.cpp Dir2/File2.cpp \[...]Dir2/File1.h` what is? the content of the file?

Comment: Yes, it is content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Awk that supports regular expressions for the record separator `RS`, it can be done like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = " +| *\\\\?\\n" } 1'
```

The advantage of this is that we are not snarfing the entire file into memory and doing some regex replacement; your input could be gigabytes long.

We basically treat the file as having two record separators: either one or more spaces, or else zero or more spaces followed by a newline, which may be preceded by an optional backslash.

Having delimited the records this way, all we have to do is output them followed by the default output record separator (`ORS`), which, of course, is newline. That is achieved by a pattern-action rule consisting of `1`.

Or a pipeline job with `sed` and `tr`, not using anything that isn't in POSIX:

```
tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/\\//g' -e 's/ \+/ /g' | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Replace newlines with spaces. Then squash runs of multiple spaces to one space while removing backslashes. Then map spaces to newlines.

Comment: `\+` is not in POSIX. The POSIX equivalent is `\{1,\}` (or use `s/  */ /g` (`<SPC><SPC>*`))

Comment: +1, the awk solution is much faster than grep one.. and the mash of tr/sed was faster than awk by a small margin for sample I used (each input line of OP's example repeated 10000 times)

Comment: Why not simply `tr '\\ ' '[\n*]' | grep .`

Comment: `tr '\\ ' '[\n*]' | grep .`  is more than twice as faster than awk solution (each input line of OP's example repeated 10000 times)

Comment: Probably better with `tr -s '\\ ' '[\n*]' | grep .`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`

```
$ cat file 
Dir1/File1.cpp Dir2/File2.cpp \
Dir3/File1.h Dir4/File2.cpp \
Dir2/File1.cpp \
Dir2/File1.h \

$ grep -o '[^\ ]*' file 
Dir1/File1.cpp
Dir2/File2.cpp
Dir3/File1.h
Dir4/File2.cpp
Dir2/File1.cpp
Dir2/File1.h
```

- `-o` extract only matching pattern
- `[^\ ]*` zero or more of non-space and non `\` characters, since `*` is greedy, it will try to match as many such characters as possible

to save the result to another file, use

```
$ grep -o '[^\ ]*' file > out_file
```

As pointed out by @Stéphane Chazelas, it is better to use the following for being more portable:

```
grep -oE '[^\ ]+' file
```

where `-E` invokes extended regex and `[^\ ]+` matches one or more of non-space and non `\` characters

**Performance analysis:**

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$_"x100000' file > file_big
$ shuf file_big -o file_big 

$ du -sh file_big 
9.0M    file_big
```

All answers and suggestions from comments used for comparison:

```
$ time grep -o '[^\ ]*' file_big > o1

real    0m2.090s
user    0m2.076s
sys 0m0.016s

$ time grep -oE '[^\ ]+' file_big > o2

real    0m1.523s
user    0m1.504s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time awk 'BEGIN { RS = " +| *\\\\?\\n" } 1' file_big > o3

real    0m0.331s
user    0m0.320s
sys 0m0.008s

$ time tr -s '\\ ' '[\n*]' < file_big | grep . > o4

real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.124s
sys 0m0.008s

$ time tr '\\ ' '[\n*]' < file_big | grep . > o5

real    0m0.105s
user    0m0.104s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Sanity check

```
$ diff -s o1 o2
Files o1 and o2 are identical
$ diff -s o1 o3
Files o1 and o3 are identical
$ diff -s o1 o4
Files o1 and o4 are identical
$ diff -s o1 o5
Files o1 and o5 are identical
```

Comment: `-o` is a GNU extension. It's now also supported by a few other implementations, but in some like ast-open's `grep`, if the pattern matches the empty string, it will run into an infinite loop. You'd want `grep -Eo '[^\ ]+'` here instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, doesn't `*` being greedy ensure it doesn't match empty string?

Comment: on an input like `Dir2/File1.h \​`, `[^\ ]*` finds 3 matches: `<Dir2/File1.h> <>\<>` (try with `sed 's/[\ ]*/<&>/g'`. GNU `grep -o` doesn't print the empty matches. ast-open does and gets stuck because (I suppose) it doesn't advance to the next character to carry on finding other matches.

Comment: is this specific to `-o` and `*` for ast-open or does it suffer for even regex like `grep 'c*'` ? either way, I will add that my answer is tested with GNU grep..

Comment: AFAIK, ast-open's `grep -o` has a problem with any pattern that matches the empty string (including `c*`, `^`, ''). In any case, `-o` being a non-standard option, there's no telling what other implementations might do with it, so yes, it's a good idea to mention it would work with GNU grep and clones (like FreeBSD's which used to be GNU grep and was then rewritten). IMO though, the `grep -Eo '[^\ ]+'` version looks more correct to me. (and is portable to ast-open's `grep`).